# Why this code is showing error at print() statement?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main() :
  for i in range(10) :
     print(randomCharacter("abcdef", end="")
  print()
def randomCharacter(characters) :
   n = len(characters) :
   r = randint(0, n - 1)
   return characters[r]
main()
```

I am trying to generate random characters

Comment: Why is it throwing a error at print() statement while running this code?

Comment: There's nothing in that second print statement in `main()` :)

Comment: `print(randomCharacter("abcdef", end=""))`

Comment: @AvrilLavigne I bet that's it, post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

print(randomCharacter("abcdef", end="") here you miss a parenthese ")"

```
print(randomCharacter("abcdef", end=""))
```

in python 3.6

```
import random as rnd

def main() :
    for i in range(10):
        print(randomCharacter("abcdefg"))
    print()
def randomCharacter(characters):
   n = len(characters)
   r = rnd.randrange(0, n - 1)
   return characters[r]

main()
```